# What action can I take to protect against TROJAN Self-Signed Cert

Tags: malware, account-security

I got an email from my network admin suggesting that one of my connected devices might be infected.

Additional information to this case:
Malwaretype: TROJAN Self-Signed Cert Observed in Various Zbot Strains

What action should I take to protect myself, and how can I ensure that none of my private information was stolen?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your 'connected devices' are computers, you need to verify that you do not have any suspicious certificates in your trusted certificate store.

Of course, [every other reaction to a trojan](https://www.bleepingcomputer.com/tutorials/how-to-remove-a-trojan-virus-worm-or-malware/) should be performed.

To review your certificate trust store:

1. In Windows - You can use a tool called RCC from [here](https://www.trustprobe.com/fs1/apps.html) to scan them automatically, or review them manually like [this](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc754841.aspx).
2. In Linux - See [this ServerFault Question](https://serverfault.com/questions/62496/ssl-certificate-location-on-unix-linux). I am not aware of a more readable way of reviewing certificates in Linux, but do try to find one if your computer is a Linux machine.